# Why does shoveling a string into a hash cause this result?

Tags: ruby

I'm working through the Ruby Koans in order to get a better grasp on Ruby and TDD. I got to Line 93 in the code in `about_hashes.rb` and this confuses me how it would be shoveled into the default constructor instead of the hash value. Just out of curiosity I tried using the same thing with a string as the parameter of the constructor and it produced a similar result.

**Now my question is why, whatever key I use, the same object is retrieved and how would I shovel a new object into the array at a specific key in a hash in the method** `test_default_value_is_the_same_object`**?**

```
def test_default_value_is_the_same_object
    hash = Hash.new([])

    hash[:one] << "uno"
    hash[:two] << "dos"

    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:one] #why not ["uno"]?
    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:two] #why not ["dos"]?
    assert_equal ["uno", "dos"], hash[:three] #why not []?

    assert_equal true, hash[:one].object_id == hash[:two].object_id
  end

def test_default_value_with_block
    hash = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

    hash[:one] << "uno"
    hash[:two] << "dos"

    assert_equal ["uno"], hash[:one]
    assert_equal ["dos"], hash[:two]
    assert_equal [], hash[:three]
end
```

Comment: "how would I shovel a new object into the array hash[:one]" - huh? like you do above. `hash[:one] << "uno"`. After that, `hash[:one]` _will_ have `"uno"`. Or were you asking something else?

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4409379

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm asking why the array at hash[:one] is the same array at hash[:two]

Comment: @marmeladze: `ruby-koans` is a meta tag, please don't create such tags, we burninated the tag for a reason, see [Burninate Project Euler](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hint as to the reason is in the name of the tests.

`test_default_value_is_the_same_object` is there to show you that when you ask for `hash[:some_value_that_doesnt_exist_yet]`, by default, you get back the default value you specified -- which is the *same object* every time. By modifying that object, you modify it for every nonexistent key. Modifying `hash[:one]` also modifies `hash[:two]`.

`test_default_value_with_block` shows the construction of a Hash using a block, which will be used to provide a new value for each key. When you do it like that, the values for `hash[:one]` and `hash[:two]` are distinct.

Comment: Thanks, I completely spaced about the keys not even being assigned anything. I tried that and printed the value and it worked like I expected. Very clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a new `Hash` with an `Array` as an accumulator when the key is not present so

```
hash = Hash.new([]) 
hash[:one] << "uno" 
hash[:one] == ["uno"] #=> true
```

but

```
hash[:two] << "dos" 
(hash[:one] == hash[:two]) && (hash[:two] == ["uno","dos"]) #=> true
hash[:three] == ["uno","dos"] #=> true
```

because `["uno","dos"]` is the original array created with the `Hash` and `hash[:non_existant_key]` points to it.

**Note:** no keys have actually been added to `hash` in this case. It would be similar to

```
 a = []
 hash = {}
 hash.fetch(:one,a) << 'uno'
 hash.fetch(:two,a) << 'dos'
 hash.fetch(:three, a) 
 #=> ['uno','dos']
 hash
 #=> {}
```

To solve this you can use this syntax as mentioned in your second test

```
hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

This means fro every new key instantiate a new `Array` as its value rather than reusing the same `Array` over and over again

This is the problem with the `Hash.new(obj)` syntax when `obj` is a mutable object

Comment: Important to note that when doing `hash[:one] << "uno"`, you are not adding new entries in the hash (and, therefore, the default-value-on-missing-key is what is always returned)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good point